# How do I De-Ess a sound file with SoX?

Tags: audio, sox

I am using SoX to create slow but pitch corrected audio files.  The resulting files sound pretty good, but often have a very hard "S" sound that I would like to filter out.  Many desktop programs include a "De-Essing" filter that works well, but I would like to have a filter that works on the server side.

What SoX filter and parameters should I use to De-Ess an audio file?

Edit: I should add that this needs to work on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

There is a LADSPA [DeEsser plugin](https://github.com/tomszilagyi/tap-plugins) that can be used from SoX. You need to have tap plugins installed and properly configured on your system. On Archlinux this can be easily achieved with

```
pacman -S tap-plugins
```

You can specify threshold and frequency as first and second arguments. I succesfully used a variant of the following command

```
# -30: threshold (dB)
# 6200: hiss frequency (Hz)
sox from.wav to.wav ladspa tap_deesser tap_deesser -30 6200
```

The filter has a fistful of other options I did not analyzed. More details can be found [here](http://tap-plugins.sourceforge.net/ladspa/deesser.html).

Answer (score 1):

While far from perfect, you may be able to get sufficient results by a suitable low-pass filter. That should not affect other parts of a speech signal too much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a de-esser VST such as [spitfish](http://www.digitalfishphones.com/main.php?item=2&subItem=5) and a command-line VST host such as [MissWatson](http://www.kvraudio.com/get/2425.html).  Sox has very limited plugin support, so if you need something more specific, you're better off going the VST route.

Comment: The Linux equivalent to VST is LADSPA. I don't know of a command-line tool for LADSPA processing but I'm sure one exists. I also don't know of a de-esser, but I'm sure one exists.